# vuejs history mode with github/gitlab pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, gitlab, vue-router, gitlab-ci

Has anyone managed to figure out how to make Vue.js work with `history mode` with GitHub or GitLab Pages?

It works with `hash mode`, but I don't want to use `hash mode` for SEO related reasons.

Reference for router modes: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution that works for me in [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/sghpa-single-page-app-hack-github-pages/#that-s-so-meta).

To summarize the solution, I created the following `404.html` file and added it to the project's root folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            // ====================================================================================================================
            // This text is simply to make sure the 404.html file is bigger than 512 bytes, else, internet explorer will ignore it.
            // Thank you internet explorer for requiring such awesome workarounds in order to work properly
            // ====================================================================================================================
            sessionStorage.redirect = location.href;
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/'">
    </head>
</html>
```

I then added this javascript in the `index.html`:

```js
(function(){
    var redirect = sessionStorage.redirect;
    delete sessionStorage.redirect;
    if (redirect && redirect != location.href) {
        history.replaceState(null, null, redirect);
    }
})();
```

Comment: This hack was working before but now it's not working any idea?

Comment: Well, it's a hack. Prone to break. The article it's based on is from 2016. 

Comment: If you care about SEO do not use this, this will tank your rankings on google. Use a proper fix and redirect back to the root file (index.html).

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about GitLab Pages, but in GitHub Pages you can serve your whole Vue.js Application through the 404.html file instead of the index.html file. Simply rename the index.html file to 404.html file on deploy.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, this has the side effect of having GitHub/GitLab serve your website with a 404 status code.

Comment: Worked for me 17/01/2021 in GitLab Pages

Comment: one problem. Main page will return 404 status instead of 200. Because of that some other tools don't want to read my site.

Comment: Worked for me, 13/07/2021 in GitlabPages - GitlabEE 12.8.6

Comment: If you care about SEO do not use this, this will tank your rankings on google. Use a proper fix and redirect back to the root file (index.html).

Answer (score 6):

Run into same issue, found this question & tried both solution above but no luck. Then tried combine them like this:

Here my `404.html` file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <script>
        // ========================================
        // Credits:
        // - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259501
        // - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50247140
        // ========================================
        const segment = 1

        sessionStorage.redirect = '/' + location.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(segment).join('/')

        location.replace(
            location.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + segment).join('/')
        )
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

And here's my `main.js` file

```js
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
    created () {
        if (sessionStorage.redirect) {
            const redirect = sessionStorage.redirect
            delete sessionStorage.redirect
            this.$router.push(redirect)
        }
    }
})

app.$mount('#app')
```

And it works

- https://feryardiant.github.io/static-spa/foo/bar/baz
- https://feryardiant.gitlab.io/static-spa/foo/bar/baz

Answer (score 6):

**GitLab Answer**

For those using GitLab there is now support to redirect to **index.html** using a `_redirects` file in your public folder.

Steps:

1. Create a file named `_redirects` in the public folder
2. Add this snippet line to that file

```
    /* /index.html 200
```

**Documentation:** https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/redirects.html#rewrite-all-requests-to-a-root-indexhtml

Comment: if anyone is looking for an example, take a look at https://gitlab.com/WaldemarLehner/vite-vue3-vuerouter-gitlab-pages-starter (code) and https://waldemarlehner.gitlab.io/vite-vue3-vuerouter-gitlab-pages-starter/ (gitlab pages instance). This specific example uses Vite as its Bundler.

Comment: In my case this additional line `/_nuxt/* /_nuxt/:splat` worked also when using custom domains

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party but I have a method to do this. I am using Vue CLI 3 and GitHub pages.

First of all, I commit all the source file into a source branch, and commit the `dist` folder (generated by Vue) to the master branch using the following shell command:

```
# deploy.sh

#!/usr/bin/env sh

# abort on errors
set -e


# build
echo Building. this may take a minute...
npm run build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd dist
# create a copy of index.html
cp index.html 404.html
find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
echo 'custom.com' > CNAME

# remove git and reinitialise
rm -rf .git
echo Deploying..
git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# deploy
git remote add origin https://github.com/User/repo.github.io
git push origin master --force

cd -
rm -rf dist
```

When GitHub pages can't find the route, it uses `404.html`. The deploy program I wrote makes a copy of index.html and names it 404.html. That's why it works.

**Edit**
Just realised that this wouldn't be good for SEO purposes as it returns a 404 response and Google won't index it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `404.html` hack https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/404.html

Or you can try to pre rendering your vue into static html
https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering-

Comment: This "hack" did not work in GitLab unfortunately. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259501/988127) worked though!

Answer (score 2):

Based on Fery's solution, I think instead of handling redirect when creating Vue instance, the [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) could work better.

I basically added a beforeEnter guard for the index route, so that the index page will be skipped and directly go to the target page.

```js
const routes = [
{
  path: '/',
  component: Index,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('redirect') !== null) {
      const redirect = sessionStorage.redirect
      delete sessionStorage.redirect
      next(redirect)
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
},
]
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

2021 Solution for vue3 & vue-cli:

Follow this with "Basic instructions":

https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages#usage-instructions

no need to change `var pathSegmentsToKeep = 0;` the 404.html.

and then in the `vue.config.js`:

```js
  // do not use "./dist/"
  publicPath: "/dist/",
  // make the index.html file place at the root of the repo
  indexPath: "../index.html",
```

then the spa is good to go~